# How do I change the minimum working frequency?

Tags: electrical-power, cpu-usage, frequency

The file

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_frequency
```

reads a value of 800 Mhz. The powertop tool also suggested that 800 Mhz w3as the minimum frequency being used.

I changed the above-mentioned file to 1.6 GHz and monitored powertop tool again. To my surprise, it still said that the minimum frequency was 800 MHz instead of 1.6 GHz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following command:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

Its output is probably one line for each core/cpu that you have saying `ondemand`. This means that when the CPU is not in use, it will go back to the lowest speed.

Btw, the files `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors` will tell you the available governors and you can take a look at [governors.txt](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/cpu-freq/governors.txt) to see the behavior of each of them.

You will have to first set the appropriate governor and then set the desired speed.

Comment: I have set it to Ondemand . I want the minimum frequency to be 1.6 Ghz instead of 800 Mhz , which I'm not able to

Comment: In that case, the easiest way is to use 'userspace' and a daemon like cpuspeed(8), which has an option for what you want (-m).